# Booting to BIOS without usb 2.0 port

Tags: intel, bios, firmware

I bought an Ainol mini pc and foolishly disabled usb 3.0 in its BIOS. Turns out the machine doesnt hv any 2.0 port and now it does not recognize my input devices during boot time, so I can no longer access BIOS using del key.

I tried rebooting directly into bios from windows, but now i can not navigate within bios because my keyboard/mouse is still not recognized. Do you have any idea to fix my mistake? Thanks for all inputs!

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cmos. If there is no jumper to do this, put out the rtc battery an wait for 15 minutes before put in again.